# Automatic Translation tool for Android

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, machine-translation

Do you know if there is any **free** automatic localization tool currently out of the market ? It would be to translate my XML files from my android project
The ones i have found all rely on Google translate API. Since this API is now paying(Since December 2011) all those tools are now obsoletes.

The ones i have tried but rely on Google Translate APIV1

- Androlate Eclipse plugin
- ailocalizer
- A Chrome extension
- Online tool : http://uzitech.com/files/translator.php

I would be really grateful if someone has found a working one.

Comment: If your app brings real value to people, you probably should think of crowdsourcing your translations instead. Having UI translated via ***any*** form of Machine Translation is a terrible idea.

Comment: I guess you are right. Do you know any free collaborative online tool which would help me on that ?

Comment: For String Follow this SO Link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49970557/5902175

Comment: you can use this faster tool https://devs.alkhalid.biz/translation/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## **Update 11.08.2018: Google not support this any more**

I've not tried it but I've heard about [Google Translate Toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit). Appears to support a wide range of formats, including Android resources.

- AdWords Editor Archive (.aea)
- **Android Resource (.xml)**
- Apple iOS
- Application (.strings)
- Application Resource Bundle (.arb)
- Chrome Extension (.json)
- GNU gettext (.po)
- HTML (.html)
- Java Application (.properties)
- Microsoft Word (.doc)
- OpenDocument Text (.odt)
- Plain
- Text (.txt)
- Rich Text (.rtf)
- SubRip (.srt)
- SubViewer (.sub)

Comment: Not perfect but it does the job.

Comment: I believe they have since removed this and now advertise third party translations.

Comment: @RyPope It has not been removed.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Just checked again, yes it has. Try uploading an android XML to it. https://i.imgur.com/nMdRka7.png

Comment: @RyPope You are wrong: http://i.imgur.com/zmi3sbv.png. I just used it to translate one of my applications for Google Play.

Comment: As what kind of file?

Comment: @RyPope strings.xml. It works perfectly.

Comment: Is it free? I can't find how to translate it w/o actually paying.

Comment: @RyPope it's still available (tried several times during the last years, and again today, in 2018), only that they are making huge publicity of the paid service. But you have the option to import it and it will be translated into the languages you selected

Comment: As of December 4, 2019, Google Translator Toolkit has shut down. Also, since November 1, 2019, Google Translate API offers $10 free tier quota per month per project.

Answer (score 3):

@Pedro Rainho tool doesn't work anymore because it uses old api key method which bing has recently changed. I have creater a GUI App using new bing secret api key apporach. You can check it. App is available at [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidresourcetranslator/)

Answer (score 3):

A similar question is answered on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473592/automatic-string-resources-translate).  I have just used Android Resource Translator (ART), freeware mentioned by "K G" above, under Windows 7 Pro.  For Windows users wanting specifically to ***translate Android resource files*** (as originally asked), this is the best free solution I've found.  (I confirm that *Google Translate* is paid, find that *memoQ* mentioned in a link above is a commercial tool).

ART installed quickly and automatically.  I selected output languages by checkbox and it automatically translated my Android app's English res/values/strings.xml file into German, Russian, and French XML files, output under a common "res" directory as values-de/strings.xml, values-ru/strings.xml, and values-fr/strings.xml in under a minute.  I then copied these directories under my project's "app/src/main/res" folder and my app has working translations.  (I played it safe; you can probably just specify your app's "res" directory for output and skip the copying).

ART uses *Bing Translate*, and there is no fee involved.  This is pure machine translation, so the result may not be as accurate as human translation, but for Android resource entries like "Download" or "Quit" accuracy seems adequate.

Warning: the GUI is unpolished.  For example:

- The Windows menu and taskbar icon are titled *Android Resource Handler* but the application window's title is *Android Resource Translator*
- I had to stretch the window on my screen to reveal its **Translate** button
- There is a field containing the text *Copy Paste your output folder path. res folder will be created here*.  Unless you manually enter a directory in this field, I'm not sure any output is generated, or where.

But these don't affect function, only convenience.

*Caveats Emptor*:

- French translation does not escape apostrophes and this causes a fatal build exception.  Workaround: edit French xml file manually replacing ' with \'.

Once I performed translations, I used Android Studio's builtin [Translations Editor](https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/android-how-to-translate-apps-in-android-studio) to validate them.

As K G says, available on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidresourcetranslator/).  Last updated 2015-02-17, 11 downloads this week.  Source code available at [github](https://github.com/khayamgondal/Android-Resource-Translator).  This is "begware;" the author includes a *Please donate* link in the app leading to a Paypal page.

Answer (score 2):

Bit more universal translation and localization service: [crowdin.com](https://crowdin.com)

Comment: Crowd.In is no longer free.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I'm about to say this, but [Bing has a free translator](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/). It can be set up using SOAP.

Here is a link to some code to help you with adding it to your app:

http://code.google.com/p/bing-translator/source/browse/trunk/src/com/saturdaycoder/bingtranslator/BingTranslatorSoapApi.java?spec=svn3&r=3

EDIT:
I just found an app that does use Bing now for the exact same reason you are looking for a new one to use.

http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/droid-translate_gghr.html

Comment: Hello, your first link is some piece of code to use Bing API. The second one is an application on Android device such as google translate but which rely on Bing, which is not what i'm looking for. I let you review my first post. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Reviewing your post didn't help. if your not intrested in an API, then what are you interested in? How about the actual Bing translator? http://www.microsofttranslator.com/

Comment: I'm not looking for an online translator, there are plenty all over the net. I need something which parse all my xml and propose me a translation for the languages of my choices

Comment: And this is an android app your looking for or just any piece of software that does it? But locally of coarse.

Comment: A piece of software that does it, Online or localy ( on my computer )

Comment: I apologize, that's what I meant. Your looking for a piece of software to use on your computer, not on the Android or to integrate into an Android App.

Answer (score 1):

old post, but I created an androlate gradle plugin you could try. https://github.com/ayvazj/gradle-androlate-plugin

Comment: its google translate free ?

Answer (score 0):

Motodev Studio has a feature that does that with the help of Google Translate.

Comment: I think Florent Valdelievre is asking if there is one that doesn't rely on Google Translate.

Comment: I think is just worried about the paying part but since Motorola is taking care of that he would not have to worry and he is just looking for a working one. And the MotoDev Studio on still works now. I would appreciate a removal of the down vote.

Comment: I didn't down vote. I just wrote a comment.

Comment: I did not vote down neither, i'm gonna give a try at MotoDev Studio and let you know if it covers my needs, Thanks

Comment: I have tried Motorola Studio and the embedded translation tool. MotoDev is using Google translate APIV2 which looks to be paying. I've got the following message returned when trying to translate : The translation service did not return a valid translation. The daily limit for accessing Google Translate API may have been reached. You may have to use your own account.
Service response message is: Please use Translate v2.  Have you been able to make it work for free ?

Comment: I used it last a while ago. Contact the motodev team .. they should be able to help/fix it. E.g. contact Eric Cloninger. http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android/MOTODEV-Studio-localization-feature-and-the-Google-Translate/td-p/15520

Comment: Thanks but It's is not necessary. APIV1 is not available anymore, APIV2 is paying, we can't do anything over google translate stuff, I need to find another solution

Comment: To use the V2 API, you have to do an update to the version 3.1 of MOTODEV Studio. As of December 20, 2011, that's only on our update site. The full installers will be available for download after everyone returns from the holidays (on or about January 6). Because of the policy change, the automated translate tool requires the user now pay for the translation. FWIW, we've investigated the Bing translate service as part of the Sequoyah project. One of my guys could write up what needs to be done if someone else wants to write the plugin and donate the work into the open source project.