# Bing Wrapper for Android

Tags: android, translation, google-translate, bing-api

We are working on an Android Project.Since Google Translate API was deprecated we are working with Microsoft Translator (BING). Is there a suitable wrapper for Bing on Android ?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Translator API is free for up to 2 million characters per month usage.

It supports the languages listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456380.aspx

It's a little confusing right now about how to access because they're in the midst of a transition from a Bing AppID mechanism for authentication towards an Azure Marketplace OAuth based one.

Details on signing up for the service and getting OAuth credentials are here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted1.aspx

The translator service can then be accessed via an HTTP service, or a SOAP Web Service. I haven't tried SOAP on Android, but if your tools can generate a proxy class (like VS does for C#/VB developers) that would be far and away the easiest way to access it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try looking at the second answer by "Chillie" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672796/automatic-translation-tool-for-android). I'm not too familiar with this, but seems like it can be set up using "SOAP". Hope that helps.

Comment: Not second, just refer to the name.